# RAD Studio Snapping to Grid on form save

Tags: delphi

I have a strange issue with RAD studio, on saving a Delphi form it is snapping components on that form to the grid. This means that I can open a form, lay it out, save it, only to find components overlapping on running the application because the form has resized itself.

This also means that whenever I check out an existing form in GIT and simply click save, the form file has been resized so that it is full of changes that I did not make.

An example:

Before:

```
  object pnlTop: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 793`
```

After:

```
  object pnlTop: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 785`
```

Is there a setting that I am missing to stop RAD studio meddling with my form layout?

I have tried turning off snap to grid in the form design options, this has no effect.

Comment: I guess you are DPI scaling your desktop?

Comment: No, my display scaling is set to 100%

Comment: And it does happen even in a brand new VCL project? Do you have any third-party plug-ins in your IDE?

Comment: Yes it happens on a brand new VCL product. I have Eurekalog, FastReports, Hydra, TMS components and virtualtreeview.

Comment: Please show a full DFM code

Comment: This happens to me too. Pretty annoying. Delphi XE3